# Continuous formula for the price of an asset paying one terminal dividend?

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, asset-pricing

I have been trying to come up with ways to come up with an answer for a question we got in my class of "Asset Pricing Theory". The question is as follows:

> "Write the price of the asset at time t in terms of the dividends at
>   time t, $D_t$. The answer is also a function of the difference between
>   $T$ (the time of the final dividend payment) and $t$."

We are given the following information:

[image]

We also know that the dynamics of consumption is given as:

$dc_t = c_t[\mu_[ct]dt+\sigma_[ct]^Tdz_t$

and that the dynamics of the dividends are given as:

[image]

I am a bit at a loss, as to where to start? Can someone perhaps provide some guidelines?